# How can I turn this routes file (koa@next -- v2) into a class with inheritance using ES6?

Tags: node.js, koa, es6-class

I basically have a file for each route name (ie: `things.js`)
With the exact same thing in each file.

I want to use ES6 classes to create a base `Route` class in `base.js` that does the default with the ability to override each request method type in the specific route file `things.js`

Here is the `things.js` route file:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const name = path.basename(__filename, '.js');

const Router = require('koa-router');
const Controller = require(`../controllers/${name}`);
const controller = new Controller();

const router = new Router({ prefix: `/${name}` });

router.get('/', controller.getAll.bind(controller));
router.post('/', controller.post.bind(controller));
router.get('/:id', controller.get.bind(controller));
router.put('/:id', controller.put.bind(controller));
router.patch('/:id', controller.patch.bind(controller));
router.delete('/:id', controller.delete.bind(controller));

module.exports = router;
```

Somehow I want the above code to be in `Route.js` and then do `class Things extends Route {}` in the event I want to change something for that specific route.

I can do inheritance when it comes to methods but not sure how I would handle these router definitions in an inheritance model.

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve this just usig a function, but since you asked for a class...

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const Router = require('koa-router');

class Route {
    constructor(name) {  
        const Controller = require(`../controllers/${name}`);
        const controller = new Controller();
        const router = new Router({ prefix: `/${name}` });
        router.get('/', controller.getAll.bind(controller));
        router.post('/', controller.post.bind(controller));     
        router.get('/:id', controller.get.bind(controller)); 
        router.put('/:id', controller.put.bind(controller)); 
        router.patch('/:id', controller.patch.bind(controller)); 
        router.delete('/:id', controller.delete.bind(controller));
    }
}

module.exports = Route;
```

Then your actual routes can be defined in their own files:

```
const Route = require('./route');
const name = path.basename(__filename, '.js');
class SomeRoute extends Route {}
```

In this form you can only override/augment the entire constructor, so if you want to, say, override behaviour for just get() routes then split the constructor up into class methods:

```
class Route {
    constructor(name) {  
        const Controller = require(`../controllers/${name}`);
        this.controller = new Controller();
        this.router = new Router({ prefix: `/${name}` });

        this.setupGet();
        this.setupPost();
        this.setupPut();
        this.setupPatch();
        this.setupDelete();
    }

    setupGet() {
        router.get('/', controller.getAll.bind(controller));
        router.get('/:id', controller.get.bind(controller)); 
    }

    setupPost() {
        router.post('/', controller.post.bind(controller));     
    }

    setupPut() {
        router.put('/:id', controller.put.bind(controller)); 
    }

    setupPatch() {
        router.patch('/:id', controller.patch.bind(controller)); 
    }

    setupDelete() {
        router.delete('/:id', controller.delete.bind(controller));
    }
}
```

Then in your individual routes you can override setupGet() and leave the other handlers as-is.

Comment: This doesn't seem very good practice to me since you are not inheriting anything really from the base class. Also how could you do this with a function instead? I'm not married to using an ES6 class, just thought that would be easiest way to override a set of defaults.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not inheriting anything really". Perhaps if you explain more specifically  what you're trying to achieve I could be of more help. You asked how you could set different behaviours for a specific route by extending a base class, which my answer shows. As for the function comment, I should have said "functionally" instead of "a function". I mentioned it because I agree that a class-based solution is overwrought, but it's what you specifically asked for.